# Why forward from one VM to another?

Tags: redirect, ssh, centos, forward

I have two virtual machines s4 and s6

When I try to ping, the results is:

```
ping s6
PING s6 (192.168.0.156) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from s6 (192.168.0.156): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms
64 bytes from s6 (192.168.0.156): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms

ping s4
PING s4 (192.168.0.154) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from s4 (192.168.0.154): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.024 ms
64 bytes from s4 (192.168.0.154): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
```

when it try ssh with s6 , the results is:
(it redirects me to s4)

```
#ssh root@s6
root@s6's password: 
Last login: Sat Jan 11 03:15:47 2014 from 192.168.0.219
[root@s4 ~]#
```

Why and how to fix this redirect?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume what's happening is that your hostname is not setup properly on s6. Try running ifconfig after your ssh root@s6. I'll bet you get 192.168.0.156.

I'm not sure how to fix this on centos, but generally there's some sort of file under /etc like hostname or somesuch that has your hostname.

Comment: I think it isn't related to hostname
when i try #ssh root@192.168.0.156 which is ip of s6
it logs in to s4 instead

Comment: What is your evidence that you are logged onto s4? The only evidence that I see is that your command prompt says s4. I am suggesting that your s6 Virtual Machine is misconfigured to report itself as being s4 (at the command prompt) but that if you run ifconfig you will find that the machine has the IP of s6.